# Calculate with time

Tags: vba, excel

As I need to log my working hours for project reasons I am trying to configure a macro. As I am rather new to VBA I am still experiencing difficulties with code formulas and time-formats.

[Here is how the sheet looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLXVg.png)

When pressing "ARRIVAL" or "DEPARTURE" it's just `Range("C7/C9") = Now`

*(this is in seperate cells because I want to be able to manually override)*

When pressing "LOG" this is the code behind it:

```
'FORMAT
Range("12:12").Insert
Range("C7").Copy
Range("C12:I12").PasteSpecial
Range("C12:I12").ClearContents

'DATE
Range("C7").Copy
Range("C12").PasteSpecial
Range("C12").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

'ARRIVAL
Range("C7").Copy
Range("D12").PasteSpecial
Range("D12").NumberFormat = "[$-F400]h:mm:ss AM/PM"

'DEPARTURE
Range("C9").Copy
Range("E12").PasteSpecial
Range("E12").NumberFormat = "[$-F400]h:mm:ss AM/PM"

'CALCULATE
Range("E12").Copy
Range("F12").PasteSpecial
Range("F12") = Range("E12").Value - Range("D12").Value

Range("C12:I12").Font.Size = 12
```

What I want now is in column G the amount of time I have been working on project which is less then 03:30h and in column H the amount of time I have been working on project which is more then 03:30h.

Ideally this would be in #Minutes and even combined in 1 column with a (+/-) so I can easily calculate the totals.

Thanks for looking into this!

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your code a bit and included some notes to explain why. I've added the 2 formulas that convert your total time into minutes and calculate the differences for the < & > requirements. Hope this helps.

```
Sub LogTime()

Range("12:12").Insert
Range("C7").Copy
'Pastes just the format from C7
Range("C12:I12").PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
'Set as Today's Date
Range("C12").Value = Date
'Arrival
Range("D12").Value = Range("C7").Value
Range("D12").NumberFormat = "[$-F400]h:mm:ss AM/PM"
'Departure
Range("E12").Value = Range("C9").Value
Range("E12").NumberFormat = "[$-F400]h:mm:ss AM/PM"
'Calculate Total with Formula
Range("F12").Value = "=" & Range("E12").Address(0, 0) & "-" & Range("D12").Address(0, 0)
Range("C12:I12").Font.Size = 12
'Convert Time To Minues: (HOUR(F12)*60)+MINUTE(F12)+ROUND((SECOND(F12)/60),0)
'< Formula: In Minutes; if Total Time is => 3:30 return 210 and Total Time if < 3:30 return Total Time
Range("G12").Value = "=IF(((HOUR(F12)*60)+MINUTE(F12)+ROUND((SECOND(F12)/60),0))>=210,210,(HOUR(F12)*60)+MINUTE(F12)+ROUND((SECOND(F12)/60),0))"
Range("G12").NumberFormat = "General"
'< Formula: In Minutes; if Total Time is <= 3:30 return 0 and if Total Time > 3:30 return total time - 3:30
Range("H12").Value = "=IF(((HOUR(F12)*60)+MINUTE(F12)+ROUND((SECOND(F12)/60),0))<=210,0,((HOUR(F12)*60)+MINUTE(F12)+ROUND((SECOND(F12)/60),0)-210))"
Range("H12").NumberFormat = "General"

End Sub
```